# Construct a vector containing intervals between the values of two other vectors

Tags: r, vector, range, intervals, higher-order-functions

I have two vectors of integers, like so:

```
c(1,5,14,24)
c(3,9,22,30)
```

I need to construct from these the vector containing the ranges between each value, concatenated together, like so:

```
c(1:3,5:9,14:22,24:30)
```

What is the best way to do this? I couldn't find another question addressing this on the site. I tried some stuff using higher order functions (Map, Fold, etc.) but they all seem to take only one list argument.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could use mapply here to get your ranges.

```
mySeq <- mapply(seq, A, B)


dput(mySeq)
# list(1:3, 5:9, 14:22, 24:30)
```

As @señor points out, if you want the ranges as a single vector, use `unlist` as well:

```
unlist(mapply(seq, A, B))
# [1]  1  2  3  5  6  7  8  9 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 24 25 26 27 28 29 30
```

Comment: If you use `unlist` then you can get the results as a vector.

Comment: @SeñorO, yes very good point, thank you.  I edited the answer to reflect

Comment: Excellent, thanks! I missed mapply; still getting to know the higher-order stuff in R. Also found out I can use `unlist` to flatten everything down to a single vector.

Comment: yep, and note that `unlist` has a useful `recursive` flag as well